# What options are available in the UK to someone who is looking to work on the road?

Tags: working-from-home

Consider a half day meeting at another site away from home. In order to make the most of the other half day, it would be helpful to have a local place to set up a laptop, with a wifi connection, and work.

In the UK there are several Co-Working locations that you can pay for on subscription, but for one-offs where you are in a town/city that you don't normally frequent, what options are available?

Coffee shops and the likes are not really an option due to the length of time and noise and privacy issues. Something more formal would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have the same problem pretty regularly. The trick for me was to change my habits around it.

Where possible I would take a train over flying as it allowed more time to work en route. Or if driving or for any reason working on the move wasn't also viable then my best bet was usually to get the travel out of the way.

Rather than straining to be near your half day meeting for the other half of the day simply get back to your own home/office/hotel room and make up the time there. You have to head back at some point so you're not losing any time by doing this, just switch mentality and realise that the solution to wanting to work somewhere private and comfortable, such as your usual place of work is, well, your usual place of work. If its too long a distance or longer trip, then frankly the hotel room is your best, most depressing friend. Sorry.

Comment: I like your last sentence. The hotel room can be a daunting place to try to work when the TV and bed are *right there*. With the WiFi and desk facilities that are usually available it probably makes for the best bet though.